# how to sort a hash with both keys and values

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash, ruby-2.0

consider a hash

```
my_hash = {"drsn"=>["on", "tw", "th"], "mhsh"=>["tw", "th", "fo"], "achu"=>["th", "fo", "fi"]}
```

i can sort the hash by

```
Hash[my_hash.sort]
```

which leads to a sorted hash like

```
{"achu"=>["th", "fo", "fi"], "drsn"=>["on", "tw", "th"], "mhsh"=>["tw", "th", "fo"]}
```

but can any one tell me how to sort **values** also along with the key ?

like

```
{"achu"=>["fi", "fo", "th"], "drsn"=>["on", "th", "tw"], "mhsh"=>["fo", "th", "tw"]}
```

i am using ruby 2.0.0

i tried `sort_by` also
like

```
Hash[my_hash.sort_by {|k,v| v.sort}]
```

but got

```
{"achu"=>["th", "fo", "fi"], "mhsh"=>["tw", "th", "fo"], "drsn"=>["on", "tw", "th"]}
```

Comment: Your example values are misleading.

Comment: @Stefan can you tell me where did you found difficult? i will change my question

Comment: `["three", "four", "five"]` is unsorted and `["five", "four", "three"]` is sorted, that looks odd.

Comment: have you checked what ["three", "four", "five"].sort gives you back?

as for as i know it sorts the values in the array alphabetically. thats what i wanted.

Comment: @h.APP.y Stefan is saying that words that express numbers (such as "three", "four", ...) imply ordering as numbers, and that makes it misleading when you want to sort the words according to a different ordering (lexicographical ordering). You used bad words as examples.

Comment: Try to explain that on the phone and you'll get my point.

Comment: ok i got it changing my  question.
thanks for noticing, i just wanted to show some junk array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with one top-level call against the hash. You need to sort the individual sub-arrays one at a time, either before or after the hash is sorted by keys.

This sorts the hash, then, for each of it's keys/values, sorts the values:

```
Hash[my_hash.sort.map { |a,b| [a, b.sort] }]
```

Comment: Thank you @meagar.
can you explain me why Hash[my_hash.sort_by {|k,v| v.sort}] did't sort with array?

Comment: Because you're sorting the sub-arrays, but not storing them anywhere. `sort_by` doesn't do anything with the values you pass it except *sort by* them. The original values remain inside `my_hash`. My version overwrites them with their sorted version.

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is misleading. You are trying to do two different things. Sorting the hash by the key (and the value in case the key is a tie) is done by:

```
Hash[my_hash.sort]
```

Sorting each value is done by:

```
my_hash.each{|_, v| v.sort!}
```

Here, `sort!` is used to modify the values, which are arrays.

Comment: can you give lilbit of explanation along with answer? it really help me like newbies.